# Visual studio code in ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, visual-studio-code

Visual studio code is getting started but not working properly in Ubuntu
[image]
Visual studio code is getting started but not working properly. The screen remains blank with some outlines. I have tried to uninstall and then install multiple times. but nothing seems to work. I have tried code --verbose and it is not showing any error, just warnings

Comment: How did you install VS Code?

Comment: Same error, I had uninstall and reinstall but seems it does not resolve. I using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the GPUCache

```
rm -rf ~/.config/Code/GPUCache
```

It works for me.